# Helper in order to copy non null properties from object to another

Tags: java

See the following class

```
public class Parent {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Date birthDate;

    // getters and setters   

}
```

Suppose I have created a parent object as follows

```
Parent parent = new Parent();

parent.setName("A meaningful name");
parent.setAge(20);
```

Notice according to code above birthDate property is null. Now I want to copy only non-null properties from parent object to another. Something like

```
SomeHelper.copyNonNullProperties(parent, anotherParent);
```

I need it because I want to update anotherParent object without overwriting its non-null with null values.

Do you know some helper like this one?

I accept minimal code as answer whether no helper in mind

Comment: Removed spring tag from this, since it has nothing to do with spring.

Comment: Removed hibernate tag from this, since it doesn't have anything to do with hibernate either.

Comment: I have solved this problem and posted the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutils-or-similar

Comment: I have solved this problem and posted the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutils-or-similar

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I supose you already have a solution, since a lot of time has happened since you asked. However, it is not marked as solved, and maybe I can help other users.

Have you tried by defining a subclass of the `BeanUtilsBean` of the `org.commons.beanutils` package? Actually, `BeanUtils` uses this class, so this is an improvement of the solution proposed by dfa.

Checking at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.java.html) of that class, I think you can overwrite the `copyProperty` method, by checking for null values and doing nothing if the value is null.

Something like this :

```
package foo.bar.copy;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean;

public class NullAwareBeanUtilsBean extends BeanUtilsBean{

    @Override
    public void copyProperty(Object dest, String name, Object value)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        if(value==null)return;
        super.copyProperty(dest, name, value);
    }

}
```

Then you can just instantiate a `NullAwareBeanUtilsBean` and use it to copy your beans, for example:

```
BeanUtilsBean notNull=new NullAwareBeanUtilsBean();
notNull.copyProperties(dest, orig);
```

Comment: an ideal answer would use the Parent class example provided in the question

Comment: I'm trying to implement your ideas but no success so far. I created a thread for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125384/copy-non-null-properties-from-one-object-to-another-using-beanutilsbean

Comment: copyProperty() is static method http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/index.html

Comment: @SergiGS BeanUtilsBean imported from Apache Commons BeanUtils that contains Vulnerabilities I don't know if it's safe to use it on an payement system solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Simply use your own copy method:

```
void copy(Object dest, Object source) throws IntrospectionException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
        InvocationTargetException {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(source.getClass());
    PropertyDescriptor[] pdList = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pdList) {
        Method writeMethod = null;
        Method readMethod = null;
        try {
            writeMethod = pd.getWriteMethod();
            readMethod = pd.getReadMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        if (readMethod == null || writeMethod == null) {
            continue;
        }

        Object val = readMethod.invoke(source);
        writeMethod.invoke(dest, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I preferred and upvoted this as it does not need 3rd party library.

Answer (score 5):

Using PropertyUtils (commons-beanutils)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : PropertyUtils.describe(parent).entrySet()) {
         if (e.getValue() != null && !e.getKey().equals("class")) {
                PropertyUtils.setProperty(anotherParent, e.getKey(), e.getValue());
         }
}
```

in Java8:

```
    PropertyUtils.describe(parent).entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
        .filter(e -> ! e.getKey().equals("class"))
        .forEach(e -> {
        try {
            PropertyUtils.setProperty(anotherParent, e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Error setting property ...;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you'ure using commons-beanutils, why not `BeanUtils.copyProperties`?

Comment: @OrangeDog, because BeanUtils.copyProperties is going to copy null into a property that must would contain a value earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I landed here after many years finding a solution, used simple java reflection to  achieve it. Hope it helps!

```
public static void copyDiff(Product destination, Product source) throws  
             IllegalAccessException, NoSuchFieldException {
for (Field field : source.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    String name = field.getName();
    Object value = field.get(source);

    //If it is a non null value copy to destination
    if (null != value) 
    {

         Field destField = destination.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
         destField.setAccessible(true);

         destField.set(destination, value);
    }
    System.out.printf("Field name: %s, Field value: %s%n", name, value);
   }
}
```

Comment: Clean solution, using only java reflection, is more secure for me. Thanks

Comment: for people who want to exculde static fileds :                          if (null != value && !java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))

Answer (score 2):

**If your setter's return type is not void, BeanUtils of Apache will not work, spring can. So combine the two.**

```
package cn.corpro.bdrest.util;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtilsBean;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;

import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/**
 * Author: BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com
 * DateTime: 2016/10/20 10:17
 */
public class MyBeanUtils {

    public static void copyPropertiesNotNull(Object dest, Object orig) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        NullAwareBeanUtilsBean.getInstance().copyProperties(dest, orig);
    }

    private static class NullAwareBeanUtilsBean extends BeanUtilsBean {

        private static NullAwareBeanUtilsBean nullAwareBeanUtilsBean;

        NullAwareBeanUtilsBean() {
            super(new ConvertUtilsBean(), new PropertyUtilsBean() {
                @Override
                public PropertyDescriptor[] getPropertyDescriptors(Class<?> beanClass) {
                    return BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(beanClass);
                }

                @Override
                public PropertyDescriptor getPropertyDescriptor(Object bean, String name) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
                    return BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptor(bean.getClass(), name);
                }
            });
        }

        public static NullAwareBeanUtilsBean getInstance() {
            if (nullAwareBeanUtilsBean == null) {
                nullAwareBeanUtilsBean = new NullAwareBeanUtilsBean();
            }
            return nullAwareBeanUtilsBean;
        }

        @Override
        public void copyProperty(Object bean, String name, Object value) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
            if (value == null) return;
            super.copyProperty(bean, name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the fact that this question is pretty old, but I thought the below answer may be useful for someone.

If you use Spring, you may try the below option.

```
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;

/**
 * Helper class to extract property names from an object.
 * 
 * @Threadsafe
 * 
 * @author arun.bc
 * 
 */
public class PropertyUtil {

    /**
     * Gets the properties which have null values from the given object.
     * 
     * @param - source object
     * 
     * @return - String array of property names.
     */
    public static String[] getNullPropertiesString(Object source) {
        Set<String> emptyNames = getNullProperties(source);
        String[] result = new String[emptyNames.size()];

        return emptyNames.toArray(result);
    }


    /**
     * Gets the properties which have null values from the given object.
     * 
     * @param - source object
     * 
     * @return - Set<String> of property names.
     */
    public static Set<String> getNullProperties(Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

        Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet<String>();
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
            Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
            if (srcValue == null)
                emptyNames.add(pd.getName());
        }
        return emptyNames;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the properties which are not null from the given object.
     * 
     * @param - source object
     * 
     * @return - Set<String> array of property names.
     */
    public static Set<String> getNotNullProperties(Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        PropertyDescriptor[] pds = src.getPropertyDescriptors();

        Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : pds) {
            Object srcValue = src.getPropertyValue(pd.getName());
            if (srcValue != null)
                names.add(pd.getName());
        }

        return names;
    }
}
```

Again you may use PropertyDescriptor and the Set from the above methods to modify the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my adaptation to copy non-null properties including ignoring properties as well using Spring BeanUtils.

```
package com.blah;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

/**
 * brett created on 10/1/20.
 * <p>
 * Modified from: https://codippa.com/skip-null-properties-spring-beanutils/
 */
public final class NullAwareBeanUtils {

    private NullAwareBeanUtils() {}

    /**
     * Copies non-null properties from one object to another.
     *
     * @param source
     * @param destination
     * @param ignoreProperties
     */
    public static void copyNonNullProperties(Object source, Object destination, String... ignoreProperties) {
        final Set<String> ignoreAllProperties = new HashSet<>();
        ignoreAllProperties.addAll(getPropertyNamesWithNullValue(source));
        ignoreAllProperties.addAll(Arrays.asList(ignoreProperties));

        BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, destination, ignoreAllProperties.toArray(new String[]{}));
    }

    @Nonnull
    private static Set<String> getPropertyNamesWithNullValue(Object source) {
        final BeanWrapper sourceBeanWrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(source);
        final java.beans.PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = sourceBeanWrapper.getPropertyDescriptors();
        final Set<String> emptyNames = new HashSet();

        for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
            // Check if value of this property is null then add it to the collection
            Object propertyValue = sourceBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(propertyDescriptor.getName());
            if (propertyValue != null) continue;

            emptyNames.add(propertyDescriptor.getName());
        }

        return emptyNames;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution relying exclusively on field manipulation through reflection with no third-party dependencies:

```
public final class NonNullFieldCopier {

    private NonNullFieldCopier() {
    }

    public static <T> void copyNonNull(T to, T from) throws IllegalAccessException {
        if (!to.getClass().equals(from.getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(to.getClass() + " is of a different type than " + from.getClass());
        }
        final List<Field> fields = getAllModelFields(from.getClass());
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            final Object fieldValue = field.get(from);
            if (fieldValue != null) {
                field.set(to, fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Field> getAllModelFields(Class<?> clazz) {
        List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            Collections.addAll(fields, clazz.getDeclaredFields());
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        } while (clazz != null);
        return fields;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use MapStruct mapper with nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappings-with-several-source-parameters
3.6. Updating existing bean instances

```
@Mapper(nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
interface OrderPatchMerger {
    void patch(Order source, @MappingTarget Order target);
}
```

On the one hand you'll have disadvantage that you need specify mappers for all pairs of classes but on the other hand you won't use reflection.

I suppose it is possible to achieve the same results by using other mappers too.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [Apache Common BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/), more specifically [the copyProperties helper in BeanUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.0/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html):

```
 BeanUtils.copyProperties(parent, anotherParent);
```

however why do you want copy only non-null properties? if a property in `parent` is null, by simply copying it you have null also in `anotherParent` right?

Just guessing... you want to update a bean with another bean?

Comment: Yes, i want to update another bean without overrides its non null values.

Comment: +1 for a sane suggestion for using libraries... sometimes I feel like we're the lone voices in the wilderness on this one

Comment: Hi, sorry but it does not work. If i have a non null anotherParent.getBirthDate() and i call BeanUtils.copyProperties(parent, anotherParent) anotherParent.getBirthDate() will return null