# PATCH java object with non-null values

Tags: java, object

I guess I could write my own version of this, but I wonder if something like this already exists in Java or a well known util. Suppose I have a class

```
public class User {
   private String name;
   private String number;
}
```

and I have the following

```
User currentUser = new User();
currentUser.setName("Bob Smith");
currentUser.setNumber("5555555555");
User updatedUser = new User();
updatedUser.setNumber("4444444444");
```

I want to be able to call something like:

```
currrentUser.patch(updatedUser);
```

and end up with:

```
currentUser.getNumber() == "444444444";
currentUser.getName() == "Bob Smith";
```

So basically I want currentUser to take all the non-null values of updatedUser. In the real world User has many more members, and might even extend another class.

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301697/helper-in-order-to-copy-non-null-properties-from-object-to-another-java

Comment: @javaguy this answer seems to deal with JavaBean which this is not

Comment: @HerbWolfe I don't have any code so far. For obvious reasons would prefer to not have to check field by field.