# Can I tell Jackson to simply set values of matching types when converting a Map to a POJO, rather than deserialising and reserialising?

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson, pojo, converters

Say I have the following class:

```java
public class MyPojo {
    public ZonedDateTime now;
}
```

To convert a `Map<String, Object>` into this POJO, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430704/1225328, `ObjectMapper#convertValue` can be used:

```java
Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
    put("now", ZonedDateTime.now());
}};
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo myPojo = objectMapper.convertValue(myMap, MyPojo.class);
```

The above code fails though, with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I think Jackson first "deserialised" the map's `ZonedDateTime` value into a `Map<String, Object>`, and then tries to rebuild a `ZonedDateTime` instance from this generated map to set the POJO's `now` property.

I don't need something that smart; is there any way to tell Jackson "if you find a value in the input map that is of the same type of the POJO property whose name matches the key, then just set it and go on"?

Comment: Maybe this can help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301697/helper-in-order-to-copy-non-null-properties-from-object-to-another-java espeachially the option that uses a stream to copy entries

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`jackson-datatype-jsr310`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.7/bundle) library to your classpath and register the `JavaTimeModule` in your `ObjectMapper` in order to serialize/deserialize `java.time` Objects properly:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

This will make your example work.