# How to use dto correctly when patching?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto

I have `UserDto`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ApiModel(value = "UserDto", description = " DTO User ")
public class UserDto {

    private Long userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String education;
    private String aboutMe;
```

I need to create update method.That's what I have now.

```
@PatchMapping("/{user}/edit")
    public ResponseEntity<String> update(@RequestBody UserDto userDto, @PathVariable long id) {
        Optional<User> optionalUser = userService.getById(id);
        if (!optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity
                    .badRequest()
                    .body("Пользователь не найден");
        }
        User user = optionalUser.get();
        userService.update(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

How can I use Dto to partial update user data? I assume I need a converter. Thanks!

Comment: Basically you'd just have to write some simple code like this: `if (userDto.getFirstName() != null) user.setFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());`

Comment: @slauth for all params?...

Comment: Yes. If you have plenty of them you could consider using a bean mapping framework like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).

Comment: The answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301697/helper-in-order-to-copy-non-null-properties-from-object-to-another discuss different ways to use common libraries to copy only non null properties.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a constructor in Entity class and transform fields from dto to entity

Comment: The question is about updating an entity, not about creating a new one.